# Buscar varios elementos en una cadena

Tags: python

Tengo una gran duda en un ejercicio que no soy capaz de resolver aún. Les comento, tengo una cadena, `dna="ATGCGAGTTGATA"`, entonces debo de encontrar la posición de las letras `G` y `C`. Para ello, lo que he estado haciendo es:

```
for base in dna:
    if base == "G"
        print dna.find("G")
        continue
```

pero esto sólo me devuelve la primera posición y no el resto de posiciones donde se encuentra `G`. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Con diccionarios (Python 3.6).

```python
dna = "ATGCGAGTTGATA"

resultados = {'G': [], 'C': []}

for indice, valor in enumerate(dna):
    if valor in ['G', 'C']:
        resultados[valor].append(indice)

print(f"Posiciones de G: {resultados['G']}")
print(f"Posiciones de C: {resultados['C']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esta sentencia `dna.find("G")` lo que estás buscando es de nuevo la letra G en la cadena, pero esta sólo trae la primera coincidencia. Ya lo estabas haciendo con el `for` si ya no hay más código, no necesitas el `continue` este únicamente sirve para "romper" el bucle y continuar con el siguiente índice si existiese. Lo que buscas es sencillo,

```
dna="ATGCGAGTTGATA"
for i,base in enumerate( dna ):
    if base == 'G':
        print( 'G encontrada en el indice ' + str( i )  )
```

Espero te puedas guiar con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar tu problema, debes agregar a tu código lo siguiente:

- Una variable para llevar el conteo de la posición de las letras
- Una lista para guardar las posiciones de la letra G
- Una lista para guardar las posiciones de la letra C

El código quedaría así:

```
dna="ATGCGAGTTGATA"
pos = 0 # Variable para llevar el conteo
posG = [] # Guardar las posiciones de la letra G
posC = [] # Guardar las posiciones de la letra C

for base in dna:
    if base == "G":
        posG.append(pos)
    if base == "C":
        posC.append(pos)
    pos += 1

print "Posiciones de G: " + str(posG)
print "Posiciones de C: " + str(posC)
```

Tu códgio inicial no funciona porque [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) solo devuelve el indice más pequeño de la palabra buscada

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usa expresiones regulares para hallar patrones de caracteres con la librería `re`

Te devuelva todas las cadenas coincidentes y la posición en la que se encuentra cada una

```
import re

dna="ATGCGAGTTGATA"

g = re.compile("G")
c = re.compile("C")

g_find = g.finditer(dna)
c_find = c.finditer(dna)

[print("Encontrada " + str(x.group()) + " en posición " + str(x.start())) for x in g_find]
[print("Encontrada " + str(x.group()) + " en posición " + str(x.start())) for x in c_find]
```